# Error in query: aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql

Hi all I have a problem with an SQL query: the problem is that if i add `GROUP BY` the database engine outputs the error:

> ```
> Column 'dbo.classes.class_name' is invalid in the select list because 
> it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
> ```

My query is:

```
string query = "SELECT p.* 
                FROM dbo.classes AS p INNER JOIN teacher_classes AS a 
                 ON a.class_id = p.class_id 
                and teach_id = @id 
                GROUP BY p.class_id";
```

Is there any help please for that.

Note without group by the query work fine but the result not grouped.

Comment: What are you grouping?  What business logic are you trying to implement?  A GROUP BY clause is only required with an aggregate function like COUNT or SUM, which obviously your query lacks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query is:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM dbo.classes AS p INNER JOIN
     teacher_classes AS a
     ON a.class_id = p.class_id and teach_id = @id
GROUP BY p.class_name;
```

You are trying to select *all* the columns from p and yet you're are grouping by class_name.  This is not allowed in most databases.  What happens if you have two classes, but information is different from them?

One option is to use `distinct` rather than `group by` to remove duplicates:

```
SELECT distinct c.*
FROM dbo.classes c INNER JOIN
     teacher_classes tc
     ON tc.class_id = c.class_id and tc.teach_id = @id;
```

Another option is to use something like `in` to find the matching classes for the teacher:

```
select c.*
from classes c
where c.class_id in (select tc.class_id from teacher_classes where teach_id = @id)
```

Notice I also changed your aliases so they have some relationship to the table names.  This makes the query much easier to read.

Comment: thanks Gordon Linoff  your answer very helpfull and my query now works fine .